# How to split up in multiple rows based on a merged column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with the columns Date and Merged_ID.

Merged_ID looks something like this:

```
18652C1
18652C5
3657C1C2
3657C1C2
3657C3C2
3657C4C2
185000C1
185000C4CC
185000C8CC
```

Its basically merging id_1 (which is the first part containing mostly numbers followed by one or more id_2. As you can see, id_2 is sometimes merged with two ids (eg C1 and C2). I know all the possibilities of id_2:

```
C1
C2
C3
CC
C4
C5
C8
```

I am looking for a way to split up this column by these ids and subsequently put them under seperate rows. The outcome should look something like this:

```
18652C1    // no change
18652C5    // no change
3657C1     // from 3657C1C2
3657C2     // from 3657C1C2
3657C1     // from the second 3657C1C2
3657C2     // from the second 3657C1C2
3657C3     // from 3657C3C2
3657C2     // from 3657C3C2
3657C4     // from 3657C4C2
3657C2     // from 3657C4C2
185000C1   // stays same
185000C4   // from 185000C4CC
185000CC   // from 185000C4CC
185000C8   // from 185000C8CC
185000CC   // from 185000C8CC
```

All this while keeping the first column as well intact (Date).

How can I achieve this column/row splitting?

Comment: When you say `df`, is this pandas? If so, I'd recommend adding the pandas tag. If it's something else, there's probably a different relevant tag you can add.

Comment: Is `CC` also a valid possibility for id_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution that works, might not be most he optimal in terms of speed, but this question is not very common, so there's no straightforward approach for this.

**edit**: I checked the speed, and it's quite decent, since all methods are vectorized, except for the `.apply` in the second row.

See comments in code for details:

*note: you need `pandas >= 0.25.0` for this, since we use the `.explode` method.*

```
# count the amount of C's in each row
c_count = df['Merged_ID'].str.count('C')

# if the amount of C's is 1, then we take the last 2 characters, else the last 4 (which is id2) and inser a space between the two id2's
id2 = pd.Series(np.where(c_count==1, df['Merged_ID'].str[-2:], df['Merged_ID'].str[-4:].apply(lambda x: x[:2]+ ' ' + x[2:])))

# we substract id1 from the string
id1 = df['Merged_ID'].str.split('C\d').str[0]

# we explode the concatenated id2's to different rows and join id1 back 
final = id1.to_frame().join(id2.str.split().explode().to_frame())

# finally we concatenate the strings back to each other
final.assign(Merged_ID = final['Merged_ID'].str.cat(final[0])).iloc[:, 0].to_frame()
```

**Output**

```
  Merged_ID
0   18652C1
1   18652C5
2    3657C1
2    3657C2
3    3657C1
3    3657C2
4    3657C3
4    3657C2
5    3657C4
5    3657C2
6  185000C1
7  185000C4
7  185000CC
8  185000C8
8  185000CC
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I solved it using regex. Have a look.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

word_output = []
index_output = []

nice_data = ['18652C1', '18652C5', '3657C1C2', '3657C1C2', '3657C3C2', '3657C4C2', '185000C1', '185000C4CC', '185000C8CC']

for i in range(len(nice_data)):
  word = nice_data[i]
  matched = re.search(r'(?<=C[0-9A-Z])(C[0-9A-Z]\b)', word)

  index_output.append(i)

  if matched:
    word_output.append(word[:-2]) #e.g. remove C2 in 3657C1C2
    word_output.append(word[:-4]+matched.group(1)) #e.g. take 3657+C2 in 3657C1C2
    index_output.append(i)
  else:
    word_output.append(word)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index_output,data=word_output)

print(df)
```

Output

```
          0
0   18652C1
1   18652C5
2    3657C1
2    3657C2
3    3657C1
3    3657C2
4    3657C3
4    3657C2
5    3657C4
5    3657C2
6  185000C1
7  185000C4
7  185000CC
8  185000C8
8  185000CC
```

Edit: Here is a bonus for you. I propose a solution with a more robust regex. It works with the original data, and also data that are contaminated with special characters.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def extracted(data):
  word_output = []
  index_output = []
  for i in range(len(data)):
    word = data[i]
    matched = re.findall(r'\W*?(\d*)\W*?(C[0-9A-Z]|)\W*?(C[0-9A-Z]\b)', word)[0]

    index_output.append(i)

    if matched[1]=='':
      word_output.append(matched[0]+matched[2]) #e.g. 18652+C1 in 18652C1

    else:
      word_output.append(matched[0]+matched[1]) #e.g. 3657+C1 in 3657C1C2
      word_output.append(matched[0]+matched[2]) #e.g. 3657+C2 in 3657C1C2
      index_output.append(i)

  return index_output, word_output

bad_data = ['@&*$&18652C1$@', '^%#18652#%@C5', '#$##3657#$#(C1C2#!&&', '@@#3657C1@#&!C2', '3657C3@&#C2', '3657C4C2@#^*', '185000C1()', '185000&*C4CC', '#%!185000C8CC']

index_output_bad, word_output_bad = extracted(bad_data)

df_bad = pd.DataFrame(index=index_output_bad,data=word_output_bad,columns=['mergedIDs'])

print('Bad Data')
print(df_bad)

nice_data = ['18652C1', '18652C5', '3657C1C2', '3657C1C2', '3657C3C2', '3657C4C2', '185000C1', '185000C4CC', '185000C8CC']

index_output_good, word_output_good = extracted(nice_data)

df_good = pd.DataFrame(index=index_output_good,data=word_output_good,columns=['mergedIDs'])

print('Good (Original) Data')
print(df_good)
```

Output

```
Bad Data
  mergedIDs
0   18652C1
1   18652C5
2    3657C1
2    3657C2
3    3657C1
3    3657C2
4    3657C3
4    3657C2
5    3657C4
5    3657C2
6  185000C1
7  185000C4
7  185000CC
8  185000C8
8  185000CC
Good (Original) Data
  mergedIDs
0   18652C1
1   18652C5
2    3657C1
2    3657C2
3    3657C1
3    3657C2
4    3657C3
4    3657C2
5    3657C4
5    3657C2
6  185000C1
7  185000C4
7  185000CC
8  185000C8
8  185000CC
```